# Как работать с проектом нескольким людям на расстоянии?

Tags: инструменты-разработчика

Мы с другом хотим сделать приложение на андроид.Есть ли возможность что бы на обоих пк появлялись внесенные нами изменения?

Comment: Github, gitlab, bitbucket в помощь... (https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/521290/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `GitHub`, проверен временем.

Comment: Проверенно забанил всех людей в Крыму, ага